# How to implement shows with this effect

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'd like to implement the functionnality i've just seen on jquery ui new web site. I need the effect shows when you click on link view source on this page http://jqueryui.com/selectable/. Someone could tell me just what plugin they used please ?

Comment: the slide down? No plugin needed for that.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You mean jquery slide down function ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it easily with something like:

```
<a id="clk" href="#">Click ME</a>
<div id="hidden">
    ALL YOU TEXT LIES HERE
</div>
```

And the jQuery code will be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#hidden").slideUp('fast', function() {});
    $("#clk").click(function() {
        $("#hidden").slideToggle('slow', function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    });
});
```

## EDIT

For fading effects, change the `slideToggle` to `fadeToggle` like so:

```
$("#hidden").fadeToggle('slow', function()
```

Working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jHyz2/) - [jHyz2](http://jsfiddle.net/jHyz2/)